# What is the distribution of the binomial distribution parameter N given sample k and p?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution

Say $k \sim Bin(N, p)$. What is the distribution of $N$, given fixed $p$ and $k$? Looks like Poisson but starting at k instead of zero (???)

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Application: I have some real number of birds ($N$), each is seen with probability $p$. I see $k$ birds and want to estimate the real number of birds ($N$).

Comment: $N$ has no distribution unless you assume one or unless you have some kind of stopping rule for a sequential experiment.  What's your situation?

Comment: My situation is as I described - I have `k` which I know is a draw from some `Bin(N, p)`, I also know p and I want to know distribution of N...

Comment: That's not sufficient information to answer the question unambiguously.  If that's *all* you know, there are two classes of answer.  One is that $N$ does not have a distribution (but you could at least compute a confidence interval for $N$).  The other is that if you assume some prior distribution for $N$, you can use Bayes' Theorem to update it based on $k$ and $p$.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that's all I know now, I also don't have any prior, moreover [I don't much believe in priors yet](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14721/how-is-the-bayesian-framework-better-in-interpretation-when-we-usually-use-uninfo) :-)

Comment: Say that I would use as much uninformative prior as possible... like  uniform distrubution from 0 to some very high number or something like that... how the distribution of N would look like then?

Comment: @whuber I don't think he's looking to perform inference and estimate N here; I think you may be confusing him by introducing priors at all (but of course this is an exercise in mind-reading). Tomas: we need more information about where this data comes from if you want a precise answer. My guess is that you are sampling from a Bernoulli distribution with parameter p until you reach k successes, and want to know the distribution of the total number of trials until this occurs. Is that correct?

Comment: @bnaul, no. I have some real number of birds (`N`), each is seen with probability `p`. I see `k` birds and want to know the real number of birds (`N`). Thank you both for reading my mind and trying to understand my question :-)

Comment: You are asking to *estimate* $N$.  You might also want to assess the error of your estimate by computing a *standard error of estimate* and/or a *confidence interval* for $N$.  However, I doubt that a binomial sampling model is accurate.  How do you know each of the $N$ birds has an equal chance of being observed and that the observations are mutually independent?  Do you even know these birds are distinct?

Comment: Guess I was way off then. In that case, I agree that a binomial model seems inappropriate here. If you're trying to estimate a population size, then there are many methods for doing so, but I am not an expert in any of them. Perhaps you should be asking about that more general problem instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Estimator for a binomial distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/estimator-for-a-binomial-distribution)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - here $p$ is fixed and the question is asking for a (posterior?) distribution while the possible duplicate is about point estimators for $n,p$.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous, but I think that you might be talking about the [negative binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution):

> ...the negative binomial distribution is a discrete probability
>   distribution of the number of successes in a sequence of Bernoulli
>   trials before a specified (non-random) number r of failures occurs.

It seems that you're asking about the number of trials needed before k successes, which is the same as N-k failures. It actually is quite close to the Poisson distribution, so your intuition was not far off.

Comment: @Tomas It's impossible to say whether this answer is correct until you clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks bnaul! Negative binomial seems great! So the distribution for `N` would then be `N ~ k + NBin(k, 1 - p)`, right?