# Difference between non-informative and improper Priors

Tags: bayesian, prior, improper-prior

I wonder what is the difference between these two kind of priors:

- Non-informative
- Improper

Comment: It might be helpful if you could provide some context here. What do you  understand about these already? Is there a particular point of confusion?

Comment: Relevant links https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175792/definition-of-improper-priors and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133707/definition-of-weakly-informative-prior/133710#133710 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73490/what-exactly-is-weakly-informative-prior

Comment: @Tim  thank you. I was looking for _non-informative_ instead of _weakly informative_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an "uninformative prior"? Can we ever have one with truly no information?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/what-is-an-uninformative-prior-can-we-ever-have-one-with-truly-no-information)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Improper priors are $\sigma$-finite non-negative measures $\text{d}\pi$ on the parameter space $\Theta$ such that$$\int_\Theta \text{d}\pi(\theta) = +\infty$$As such they generalise the notion of a prior distribution, which is a probability distribution on the parameter space $\Theta$ such that$$\int_\Theta \text{d}\pi(\theta) =1$$They are useful in several ways to characterise

1. the set of limits of proper Bayesian procedures,which are not all proper Bayesian procedures;
2. frequentist optimal procedures as in (admissibility) complete class theorems such as Wald's;
3. frequentist best invariant estimators (since they can be expressed as Bayes estimates under the corresponding right Haar measure, usually improper);
4. priors derived from the shape of the likelihood function, such as non-informative priors (e.g., Jeffreys').

Because they do not integrate to a finite number, they do not allow for a probabilistic interpretation but nonetheless can be used in statistical inference if the marginal likelihood is finite$$\int_\Theta \ell(\theta|x)\text{d}\pi(\theta) < +\infty$$since the posterior distribution$$\dfrac{\ell(\theta|x)\text{d}\pi(\theta)}{\int_\Theta \ell(\theta|x)\text{d}\pi(\theta)}$$is then well-defined. This means it can be used in exactly the same way a posterior distribution derived from a proper prior is used, to derive posterior quantities for estimation like posterior means or posterior credible intervals.

> **Warning:** One branch of Bayesian inference does not cope very well with improper priors, namely when testing sharp hypotheses. Indeed
>   those hypotheses require the construction of two prior distributions,
>   one under the null and one under the alternative, that are orthogonal.
>   If one of these priors is improper, it cannot be normalised and the
>   resulting Bayes factor is undetermined.

In Bayesian decision theory, when seeking an optimal decision procedure $\delta$ under the loss function $L(d,\theta)$ an improper prior $\text{d}\pi$ is useful in cases when the minimisation problem
$$\arg \min_d \int_\Theta L(d,\theta)\ell(\theta|x)\text{d}\pi(\theta)$$
allows for a non-trivial solution (even when the posterior distribution is not defined). The reason for this distinction is that the decision only depends on the product $L(d,\theta)\text{d}\pi(\theta)$, which means that it is invariant under changes of the prior by multiplicative terms $\varpi(\theta)$ provided the loss function is divided by the same multiplicative terms $\varpi(\theta)$,$$L(d,\theta)\text{d}\pi(\theta)=\dfrac{L(d,\theta)}{\varpi(\theta)}\times\varpi(\theta)\text{d}\pi(\theta)$$

Non-informative priors are classes of (proper or improper) prior distributions that are determined in terms of a certain informational criterion that relates to the likelihood function, like

1. Laplace's insufficient reason flat prior;
2. Jeffreys (1939) invariant priors;
3. maximum entropy (or MaxEnt) priors (Jaynes, 1957);
4. minimum description length priors (Rissanen, 1987; Grünwald, 2005);
5. reference priors (Bernardo, 1979, 1781; Berger & Bernardo, 1992; Bernardo & Sun, 2012)
6. probability matching priors (Welsh & Peers, 1963; Scricciolo, ‎1999; Datta, 2005)

and further classes, some of which are described in Kass & Wasserman (1995). The name non-informative is a misnomer in that no prior is ever completely non-informative. See my [discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20535/7224) on this forum. Or Larry Wasserman's [diatribe](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiIh4b0i6_UAhXLI8AKHd1oBnkQFggxMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnormaldeviate.wordpress.com%2F2013%2F07%2F13%2Flost-causes-in-statistics-ii-noninformative-priors%2F&usg=AFQjCNEqYW_pUZhHv5enRrbQlTgc9F_8xg&sig2=DRRMcXmMpfe44Wux4H6VMQ). (Non-informative priors are most often improper.)

Answer (score 9):

A non-informative prior, rigorously speaking, is not a prior distribution. This is a function such that, if we consider it as if it were a distribution and apply Bayes' formula, we get a certain posterior distribution, which aims to reflect as best as possible the information contained in the data and only in the data, or to achieve a good *frequentist-matching property* (i.e. a $95\%$-posterior credible interval is approximately a $95\%$-confidence interval).

A non-informative prior is often "improper". A distribution has a well-known property: its integral equals one. A non-informative prior is said to be improper when its integral is infinite (therefore in such a case it is clear that it is not a distribution).

Comment: I consider this definition of a "non-informative" prior to be super-restrictive!

Comment: @Xi'an In view of the shortness of the OP, I think this short answer is rather appropriate.

Comment: @Xi'an It's a quote of Bernardo (more or less). Me I agree ^^

Comment: @Xi'an I will paste the quote when I go home if you want. See you later.

Comment: @Xi'an I'm not at home yet but eg [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring09/other-readings/bernardo-reference-priors.pdf) *Reference posteriors are obtained by formal use of Bayes theorem with a reference
prior function*. Benardo says reference prior **function**, not distribution.

Comment: More seriously @Xi'an, you mean it's restrictive to Bernardian noninformative priors ? That's right, and some others maybe. I know you have more knowledge than me in this topic. But I'm Bernardo-oriented (and matching priors).