# Properties of MaxEnt posterior distribution for a die with prescribed average

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, maximum-entropy, uninformative-prior

Question: after throwing a die a large number of times and discovering that the average of the outcomes is $4$, what probability distribution one should assign to statements "the next roll will be $i$" for $i = 1, 2, \dots, 6$?

E.T. Jaynes in Chapter 9 of the book "Probability Theory: The Logic of Science" derives the following:

> if we start with ignorance knowledge, $I_0$, meaning that all
>   individual rolls are independent and are equally likely to occur, so
>   $1/6$ for each outcome, then we just need to find $(p_1, p_2, \dots, p_6)$ that maximises $H(p_1, p_2, \dots, p_6) := \sum_{i=1}^6 -p_i \log p_i$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^6 i  p_i = 4$.

Utilising Lagrange multipliers one can easily derive Boltzmann posterior distribution for such a die. My posterior distribution, found numerically, is the following:

$$(p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5, p_6) \approx (0.10,0.12,0.15,0.17,0.21,0.25).$$

Moreover E.T. Jaynes advocates that such posterior distribution is the only answer consistent with prior knowledge $I_0$, the data $D=\{\text{the mean is $4$}\}$ and [Cox's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox's_theorem). However, I have a few questions about such posterior:

1) Qualitative: does it really do what common sense dictates it should do? Why the posterior doesn't have more mass on $4$?

2) Why the mode of the posterior is $6$ rather than $4$? Under what loss function should I guess 4?

3) Why the MLE approach fails to give the mode of the posterior distribution, despite the following quote:

> A maximum likelihood estimator coincides with the most probable Bayesian estimator given a uniform prior distribution on the parameters. ([Wiki: MLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood)).

---

P.S. Haskell code used for finding the answer:

```
l = concat $ map (\a -> [(-a), a]) l'
    where
         l' = map (/ 1000) [1.. ]

findExp xs = sum $ zipWith (*) [1..] xs

entropy xs = sum $ map (\a -> - a * (log a)) xs

probs lam = map (/ sum probs') probs'
      where
           probs' = map (\a -> exp (-lam * a)) [1..6]

expectation  = 4.0

condition lam = abs (findExp (probs lam) - expectation) <= 0.05

main = print dist >> print (findExp dist) >> print (entropy dist)
      where
        lamda = head (dropWhile (not . condition) l)
        dist = probs lamda
```

Comment: The short answer is that there is no such thing at _the_ non-informative prior. See this [entry from Cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20520/7224).

Comment: The reason why there's not more weight on 4 is that the cases that have more weight on 4 (but are consistent with the other aspects of the question) all have lower entropy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MaxEnt algorithm heavily favors distributions as close to uniform as possible. Therefore, given the constraint that the average is $4$, it is more optimal to add more mass to $6$ rather than $4$ in order for the posterior to stay close to uniform.

Why such tendency? Perhaps it has something to do with the shortest message possible. It's *simple* to encode distributions close to the uniform. Why? Well, the uniform distribution is at the extreme end of this: instead of encoding $(\frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6})$ one gets away with encoding roughly $[6, \frac{1}{6}]$. I.e. $\frac{1}{6}$ $6$-times.

So what MaxEnt does is akin to Occam's razor/minimum message length and the like: through the space of all possible explanations (posteriors) it finds the simplest one which explains the data. And then it tells you that the simplest one is most likely: so if I were to encode each posterior as a binary string, the entropy of each string could itself be renormalised as some probability measure. The shortest string is then just the mode of such entropy-probability-measure on all strings.

My intuition called for $4$ to have more mass but perhaps it was just a fallacy of my own intuition: given the above reasoning I find it plausible that guessing $6$ is the right thing to do if I am rewarded only when I guess a toss correctly.

On the other hand, it seems that conditioning on the most probable hypothesis is short-sighted: it ignores all other gains to be made from other hypotheses which are not likely, but plausible. Therefore a very important question arises: when conditioning on the mode of the entropy-probability-measure is equivalent to taking the expectation with respect to entropy-probability-measure? I suspect that MaxEnt distribution is simply the expectation of this entropy-probability-measure, so always.

As for the loss functions which would force me to guess $4$, it is a well-known result that if my loss-function is a mean-squared error, I should guess the expectation of the posterior, which is, of course, $4$.

I am yet to connect this with MLE's... So to be continued/edited.

Answer (score 1):

A Bayesian inference of the posterior probabilities given prior uniform probabilities is closer to what you had in mind. Because, indeed, the likelihood for getting a 4 for a loaded dice that has a large probability of 4 is high.

The "problem" is that that inference results in a posterior non-uniform distribution *even* for a fair dice, with an average value of 3.5. That is for the very same reason: some loaded dices also result in an average value of 3.5. So even as $N \to \infty$ the posterior is different form a the uniform distribution that MaxEnt would give you.

Uffink explained that with much more detail, here:
http://www.projects.science.uu.nl/igg/jos/mep2def/mep2def.pdf

Comment: If mean is $6$ MaxEnt results in $(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)$ *because* number of throws, $N$, was taken to be $\infty$. MaxEnt is the *limitting* distribution as the number of throws goes to $\infty$.

Comment: His table 1 departs from MaxEnt solution because MaxEnt assumes all outcomes (represented as infinite strings of $1 \dots 6$) are equally likely, *not* all frequences $(N_1, N_2, N_3, N_4, N_5, N_6)$. "Problem" is only a problem if one doesn't follow MaxEnt derivation, found in Chapter 9 of Jayne's book.

Comment: So in his equation $(40)$, *not all* $P(N_1, N_2, \dots, N_6)$ are equal.