# Can I convert a frequentist p-value into a Bayesian Posterior Probability

Tags: bayesian, p-value, frequentist, teaching

I am drafting a teaching session for fellow clinicians to try and provide a somewhat intuitive understanding on how Bayesian statistics differs from the frequentist methods we are taught at medical school.
In the session I propose an implausible intervention that is studied and happens to find a difference in sample means with a p-value of 0.048. We then go through comparing the 'oddness' of the results with the 'oddness' of the implausible intervention working.
I describe Bayes method of comparing these oddities to try and find which is the least implausible.
I turn to [this calculator](https://www.gigacalculator.com/calculators/bayes-theorem-calculator.php) because it uses more concrete inputs than other formulations that need more abstract inputs such as p(data).
I then go on to fiddle around with some of the inputs to help build an intuitive sense of what very low p-values achieve.

In my example I use it as follows:

- Calculate the probability of: **H<sub>0</sub>**
- Based on the probability of: **p-value**
- P(**H<sub>0</sub>**): 0.999 (I use an average of the class's priors)
- P(**p-value**|**H<sub>0</sub>**): 0.048 (this is the outcome p-value)
- P(**p-value**|**¬H<sub>0</sub>**): 0.8 (I have **assumed** this is the same as study power)

Questions:

1. Is P(**p-value**|**¬H<sub>0</sub>**) the same as a study power? Or is it only it only the same as the study power if the p-value = the "cut-off p-value". I.e, it varies with the observed p-value?
2. If not, what is it and how could I estimate it and explain it?
3. Is my methodology valid?

Comment: "Testing a Point Null Hypothesis: The Irreconcilability of P Values and Evidence", James O. Berger and Thomas Sellke, Journal of the American Statistical Association, Vol. 82, No. 397 might be relevant here

Comment: The notation is confusing/incorrect. The p-value should be something like p=Pr{data|H0} where you'd need to define "Pr", "data" and "H0" carefully. (Pr is long-run relative frequency, data is statistic as observed or more extreme, H0 means the null is true and test assumptions hold). Also the power is computed under a specific alternative hypothesis. You can't leave it at "not H0".

Comment: That being said, it may be interesting to read this blog by Daniel Lakens: [The relation between p-values and the probability H0 is true is not weak enough to ban p-values](http://daniellakens.blogspot.com/2015/11/the-relation-between-p-values-and.html) and references therein. Note however that the post ends with "If you really want to make statements about the probability the null-hypothesis is true, given the data, p-values are not the tool of choice (Bayesian statistics is)."

Comment: Your project seems doomed to fail for the following reasons. Testing a null addresses the question: Are the data reasonably consistent with the null hypothesis? A p-value is a measure of this consistency, and can be regarded as a measure of the *absolute plausibility* of the null. A different question is: Given the data and two competing hypotheses, what is the *relative plausibility* of each? Posterior probabilities are Bayesian answers for the relative plausibilty of question.

Comment: Different questions often require different answers, so it can hardly be surprising that p-values are not useful as measures of relative plausibility (something the Berger and Sellke paper should have acknowledged). *P-values work perfectly well for the job that they are designed for.*

Comment: The closest analogue to a p-value in Bayes world is the [prior predictive probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/394648). If you squint, you can view the frequentist $H_0$ as a [prior with point mass at $\beta_0$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/209909).

Comment: Thank you all for you input and it seems perhaps that I don't have the necessary depth of understanding of these concepts. Perhaps I should state it in a simpler form. Is the p-value not P(data|H0)? If it is, why can't I use Bayes' Theorem to calculate P(H0|data) provided I have the other necessary inputs?

Comment: "Is the p-value not P(data|H0)?" Not exactly. If x is the observed data then p-value = P(Observing data as extreme or more extreme as x|H0). The reason that frequentists cannot use Bayes Theorem for this application is because when H0 concerns a parameter, it is either true or false so P(H0)) = 0 or 1, making applying Bayes Theorem pointless.  In contrast, a Bayesian picks a number (any number) between 0 and 1 for their P(H0), and can then plug that into Bayes Theorem and produce a posterior probability.

Comment: I think a great session for the clinicians would be to get them to write down their own prior for the example you have, then ask say 5 of them what their priors are, input those priors one at a time into the Bayes calculator to get 5 posteriors, and report the 5 Bayesian answers back to the class. Then have a discussion about the pros and cons of both methods.

Comment: Ok thanks for this. I think I will carry on as planned, but I will be clear to caveat that the posterior generated is not necessarily a true value. But that the process is indicative of how priors and 'p-values'/frequentists statistic combine to produce a posterior that is more suggestive of whether a treatment actually works. I.e that extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence, and that p<0.05 is generally a weak threshold to base changes in clinical practice on unless the prior is high. I will also describe that there are separate Bayesian methodologies

Answer (score 1):

> Can I convert a frequentist p-value into a Bayesian Posterior Probability

No.

Bayes theorem is

$$P(H_0|\text{data}) = \frac{P(\text{data}|H_0)}{P(\text{data})} \cdot P(H_0)$$

as mentioned in the comments, this $P(\text{data}|H_0)$ is not the same as a p-value.

---

Related questions

- [What is the information in an exact p-value?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630411/)

  In some cases a p-value can be regarded as a sufficient statistic and, in a way, can be used for computations in inference like the computation of a posterior probability.
- [Expressing one-sided p values of directional hypothesis tests as Bayes factors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429130/)

  credible intervals and confidence intervals may potentially coincide. For such cases p-values can be used to express computations with credible intervals.