# Appropriate forecasting model

Tags: forecasting, econometrics, exponential-smoothing

I only have 2 available points and I wish to forecast its value for the next year. I'm currently looking into exponential smoothing, and econometric input-output model. Which one would be more appropriate? This is about poverty.

Comment: With just two points you don't have all these choices.  All you have is an estimated slope which means that prediction can only be done by extending the straight line.  When you get more data you may have other options.

Comment: @Michael Chermick Can I possibly use exponential smoothing since what I only need there is an actual and forecasted value?

Comment: Another option somewhat less intrusive in my opinion is to simply average the values. This seems to me to be between fitting a trend line and using the last value.

Comment: ...although the forecast itself with not be between the forecast from the trend and the last value (just to note).

Comment: I think all the mentioned ideas are plausible but it is unclear which will be most accurate.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I only have 2 available points."

Comment: I'm seeing that you asked essentially the same question 3 hours earlier at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270287/causal-forecasting - please put all your relevant info into one and delete the other.