# Objective Bayesianism: Jeffreys priors vs reference priors vs principle of transformation groups

Tags: bayesian, prior, uninformative-prior, jeffreys-prior, improper-prior

According to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20535/82547),

> José Bernardo has produced an original theory of reference priors where he chooses the prior in order to maximise the information brought by the data by maximising the Kullback distance between prior and posterior. In the simplest cases with no nuisance parameters, the solution is Jeffreys' prior. In more complex problems, (a) a choice of the parameters of interest (or even a ranking of their order of interest) must be made; (b) the computation of the prior is fairly involved and requires a sequence of embedded compact sets to avoid improperness issues.

My question is this: Is there a simple example where Bernardo's reference prior, the [Jeffreys prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior), and the [principle of transformation groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_transformation_groups) (a generalization of the principle of indifference) all exist and all yield different results?

Comment: As soon as you separate the parameter into groups, Jeffreys prior and reference prior differ. As for the transformation groups they only exist in some settings, a Poisson distribution being a first counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case where you have a multivariate Bernoulli distribution where the variables are all dependent (i.e. non-trivial).

- Jeffery's Prior gives you: (simple multivariate generalization of) Beta(0.5,0.5)
- Jayne's Prior gives you: (simple multivariate generalization of) Beta(1,1) (the Uniform incidentally *the same as Laplace prior in this case*)
- Bernardo's Prior gives you: "something better" (Jeffery's prior *'breaks down'* in multivariate cases, hence motivation for Bernardo)

P.S. I believe the reason that Jeffery's prior breaks down is because it reduces the entire fisher information matrix to a one scalar ( $p(\vec \theta) \propto \sqrt{det I(\vec \theta)}$). Which oversimplifies the multi-dimensional information it contains.

References:

1. https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/uninformative-prior
2. [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture7.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture7.pdf)