# How does one place an uninformative prior on a Gamma Distribution?

Tags: bayesian, prior, gamma-distribution, uninformative-prior

I'd like to choose an uninformative prior for the scale and shape parameters of the Gamma distribution. Any help and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no completely 'flat' gamma prior among proper distributions (with densities integrating to unity). The closest you can get is to use _very_ small shape and rate parameters. (Then, for example, with a Poisson likelihood, the posterior depends very largely on the likelihood and hardly at all on the prior.)

Comment: The use of "uninformative" or "noninformative" should be abandoned in favour of "reference" as there is no such thing (see my answer [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20535/7224)). One approach to reference priors is Jeffreys', which alas involves a digamma function for the shape parameter, unless one restricts the shape to be an integer.