# Are there any uninformative priors with an unlimited support like $(-\infty,\infty), (0,\infty), (-\infty,0)$?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, uninformative-prior

The Bayes theorem is:

$P(\theta | x)=\displaystyle \frac{p(\theta)L_x(\theta)}{\int_{\theta \in A}p(\theta)L_x(\theta)d\theta}$

It's pretty clear that $\theta's$ support will not change as bayes theorem update its distribution given some data, if $\theta's$ support is $(a,b)$ so it's easy to define a uninformative prior ( I'd just use $U(a,b)$) but when the support is either:

- $A=(-\infty,\infty)$
- $A=(0,\infty)$
- $A=(-\infty,0)$

it becomes trouble to get a non-informative prior like $U(a,b)$ so Is there any alternative for a uninformative prior distribution to get through this?

Comment: Why do you need an uninformative prior? [Such a thing doesn’t really exist.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/what-is-an-uninformative-prior-can-we-ever-have-one-with-truly-no-information). If you really need, why not just using an improper “flat” prior?

Comment: There is almost no prior information where I work.I've never been told about what flat prior is.