# Does it make sense to do a prior sensitivity analysis if using flat priors (Mplus default)?

Tags: bayesian, prior, sensitivity-analysis, mplus

If it does make sense to do a sensitivity analysis how should one determine which priors to use? If flat "non-informative" priors are chosen to begin with because of a lack of information then it seems quite hypothetical choosing different informed priors to sensitivity check?

Comment: Yes, because flat priors can lead to posterior impropriety which may be revealed by switching them out for something more informative.

Comment: Flat priors are not "non-informative" and their choice carries consequences, hence must be assessed by a sensitivity check.

Comment: As @Xi'an wrote, flat priors are *not* non-informative. They are the formal equivalent of saying "every parameter value from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ is equally unsurprising to me," which, if you think about it, *is* a meaningful statement.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things. First, as @Xi'an points out, flat priors are not non-informative, as all priors contain some specification analogous to some type of information (see @Xi'an's previous answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/what-is-an-uninformative-prior-can-we-ever-have-one-with-truly-no-information) for more information). Second (and in light of the first point), I cannot think of a good reason why doing a sensitivity analysis is not a good idea. Sure, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the impact of the prior on the likelihood diminishes. However, even with an absurdly large sample, I would still conduct a sensitivity analysis and place it in an Appendix. Finally, for more information on the use of priors in `mplus`, I recommend MacCallum, Edwards, & Cai (2012) and Smid & Winter (2020).

**References**

MacCallum, R. C., Edwards, M. C., & Cai, L. (2012). Hopes and cautions in implementing Bayesian structural equation modeling.

Smid, S. C., & Winter, S. D. (2020). Dangers of the defaults: A tutorial on the impact of default priors when using Bayesian SEM with small samples. Frontiers in Psychology, 11, 611963.

Comment: Another helpful resource regarding the dangers of the default (flat) priors in SEM is [Smid & Winter (2020)](https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2020.611963).

Comment: @Durden Thanks for the reminder! I really like that article (I believe I have cited in in a previous CV post).