# Bayesian Multiple Regression with Interaction

Tags: r, bayesian, interaction, biostatistics, jags

I want to perform a Bayesian analysis (multivariate regression with an interaction term) using this model:

**DEP ~ beta0 + beta1*X1 + beta2*X2 + beta3*(X1*X2)**

DEP = Dependent variable (continuous)

X1 = continuous independent variable

X2 = categorical independent variable (levels: -1 and 1)

X1*X2 = interaction term, which is meant to examine the different effects of X1 between the two groups (X2, levels: -1 and 1)

After reading a book about bayesian modelling, I was able to create some results. However, I still get divergent results from my frequentist analyses. I've been using this model for MCMC in JAGS:

```
# THE MODEL.
  modelString = "
  # Standardize the data:
  data {
    ym <- mean(y)
    ysd <- sd(y)
    for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
      zy[i] <- ( y[i] - ym ) / ysd
    }
    for ( j in 1:Nx ) {
      xm[j]  <- mean(x[,j])
      xsd[j] <-   sd(x[,j])
      for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
        zx[i,j] <- ( x[i,j] - xm[j] ) / xsd[j]
      }
    }
  }
  # Specify the model for standardized data:
  model {
    for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
      zy[i] ~ dt( zbeta0 + sum( zbeta[1:Nx] * zx[i,1:Nx] ) , 1/zsigma^2 , nu )
    }
    # Priors vague on standardized scale:
    zbeta0 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1/2^2 )
    for ( j in 1:Nx ) {
      zbeta[j] ~ dnorm( 0 , 1/2^2 )
    }
    zsigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-5 , 1.0E+1 )
    nu ~ dexp(1/30.0)
    # Transform to original scale:
    beta[1:Nx] <- ( zbeta[1:Nx] / xsd[1:Nx] )*ysd
    beta0 <- zbeta0*ysd  + ym - sum( zbeta[1:Nx] * xm[1:Nx] / xsd[1:Nx] )*ysd
    sigma <- zsigma*ysd
  }
  " # close quote for modelString
```

From my frequentist approach, the estimate of the interaction term is -.12. The posterior distribution for the interaction term, however, has a mode of .17 (see picture). Could someone please help me in figuring out why this discrepancy exists? I would be highly thankful for any help or suggestions!

[image: the observed posterior distribution]

Comment: Why would they be the same? It's a different model. It includes priors, your frequentist results don't.

Comment: @Tim They should converge at least to some degree, shouldn't they? Now the effect is in the opposite direction of my frequentist analyses, which does not seem right to me. I also chose broad priors that should not affect the results too much.

Comment: [Every prior does affect the results.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/what-is-an-uninformative-prior-can-we-ever-have-one-with-truly-no-information) Those two models are different, so the result can differ.

Comment: @Tim Why would the results go in the opposite direction? I understand that the choice of my prior affects the posterior, but the tendency should nevertheless be the same, correct? Would you have an idea of how to make my Bayesian approach more valid in this case?

Comment: The two trivial culprits: you have a bug in the code somewhere, or your model definition differs in both cases (other than using priors). The third reason is that you're using a different model, the results of using two different models can be... different. It doesn't make any of the models more valid. The signs of the parameters don't need to be the same when using different models.

Comment: @Tim I understand that either the code or my model is wrong. I do not think that the code is wrong, as I have mainly adapted it form the code of the book. However, I also have no idea what could be wrong with my model. Do you have any advise for me how to fix this or can you spot any potential mistakes? Also let me know if I have not provided enough information Thank you!

Comment: Nothing needs to be wrong with the model. Using priors is like using regularization in the frequentist model, regularized models give different results than non-regularized ones.

Comment: @Tim As I understand my model, I have used the following prior distribution: 

zbeta0 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1/2^2 )

This would be a vague prior distribution for the standardized regression coefficients centred around 0. If I run the analyses using a frequentist approach, I get a highly significant term that is negative (-.12). According to this rather unspecific prior, centred around 0; I would expect to observe an effect that goes in the same direction as my frequentist analyses. Doesn't that mean that something in the model is off? How do I figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Nothing needs to be wrong there, though before jumping to conclusions, check your code for bugs and double check the model definitions and the assumptions you made when defining the model.