# Estimator for a binomial distribution

Tags: estimation, binomial-distribution

How do we define an estimator for data coming from a binomial distribution? For bernoulli I can think of an estimator estimating a parameter p, but for binomial I can't see what parameters to estimate when we have n characterizing the distribution?

Update:

By an estimator I mean a function of the observed data. An estimator is used to estimate the parameters of the distribution generating the data.

Comment: What is your understanding of an "estimator"?  I wonder about that, because estimators don't have "parameters."  It makes me concerned that you aren't clearly communicating your question.  Maybe you could give a concrete example of an actual situation you're considering.

Comment: @whuber added more information. let me know if you want me to add more details or if my understanding is flawed.

Comment: The edit is correct, but a concrete example would still help.  In many applications of the Binomial distribution, $n$ is not a parameter: it is given and $p$ is the only parameter to be estimated.  For example, the count $k$ of successes in $n$ independent identically distributed Bernoulli trials has a Binomial($n$,$p$) distribution and one estimator of *the sole* parameter $p$ is $k/n$.

Comment: If n is predefined then the pmf is given for n trials. An estimator would however be a function of N data points. Would it still be ok to consider each of these N observed data points as N independent variables given we have the pmf defined in terms of a constant n.
What about the case when we have to estimate both n and p?

Comment: I would love to see an example, even a contrived one, of estimating both $n$ and $p$ (in a frequentist setting).  Think about it: you observe a *single* count, *k*, say $k=5$. We expect $k$ approximately to equal $n p$.  So do we estimate $n=10$, $p=0.5$?  Or maybe $n=5000$, $p=0.001$?  Or almost anything else? :-)  Or are you suggesting you might have a series of independent observations $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m$ all from a common Binomial$(n,p)$ distribution with both $p$ and $n$ unknown?

Comment: I am suggesting the latter - both p and n are unknown. I want an estimator for both n and p as a function of N observed data points.

Answer (score 12):

I guess what you are looking for is the probability generating function. A derivation of the probability generating function of the binomial distribution can be found under

http://economictheoryblog.com/2012/10/21/binomial-distribution/

However, having a look at Wikipedia is nowadays always a good idea, although I have to say that the specification of the binomial could be improved.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Specification

Answer (score 3):

Say you have data $k_1, \dots, k_m \sim \text{iid binomial}(n, p)$.

You could easily derive method-of-moment estimators by setting $\bar{k} = \hat{n}\hat{p}$ and $s_k^2 = \hat{n}\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$ and solving for $\hat{n}$ and $\hat{p}$.

Or you could calculate MLEs (perhaps just numerically), eg using `optim` in R.

Comment: It turns out the MLEs are really horrible for $p \lt 1/2$--they are biased and hugely variable, even with large samples.  I haven't studied the MM estimators, in part because they're frequently not even defined (whenever $s^2/\bar{k} \gt 1$, which happens).

Comment: @whuber - he didn't ask for a _good_ estimator. ;)

Comment: Why not just propose $\hat{n}$=17 and $\hat{p}=1/2$ no matter what, then? :-)  But you have a point: the question doesn't even specify *what* is to be estimated.  If we only need an estimator for $np$, then there's an obvious good one available.

Comment: @whuber - Indeed.  And I wouldn't be surprised to find $\hat{n} \approx \max k_i$ for the MLE.

Comment: That's correct: especially when $p$ is close to $1$, the max of the counts is the MLE.  It works pretty well in such cases, as you might imagine.  For smaller $p$, even with lots of data it's hard to distinguish this from a Poisson distribution, for which $n$ is effectively infinite, leading to an enormous uncertainty in the estimate of $n$.

Comment: I do not understand the reasoning that the MLE would be worse for $p<1/2$ than for $p>1/2$ since the model is symmetric in $p$... Observing $X_i\sim B(n,p)$ is the same as observing $(n-X_i)\sim B(n,1-p)$.

Answer (score 1):

Every distribution have some unknown parameter(s). For example in the Bernoulli distribution has one unknown parameter probability of success (p). Likewise in the Binomial distribution has two unknown parameters n and p. It depends on your objective which unknown parameter you want to estimate. you can fix one parameter and estimation other one. For more information see [this](http://itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366i.htm)

Comment: What if I want to estimate both the parameters?

Comment: For maximum likelihood estimation, you have to take derivative of the likelihood function with respect to interested parameter(s) and equate that equation to zero, and solve the equation. I mean to say the procedure is same as you did while estimating 'p'. You have to do same with 'n'. check this one www.montana.edu/rotella/502/binom_like.pdf

Comment: @love Your reference estimates only $p$, taking $N$ as fixed.

Comment: -1 @love-stats For an example of a situation where taking the derivative of the likelihood function, equating it to $0$, etc. _does not work_, see [this attempt](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41638/6633) and [the correct solution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41473/6633)

Answer (score 1):

I  think we could use method of moments estimation to estimate the parameters of the Binomial distribution by the mean and the variance.

---

Using the method of moments estimation to estimate The parameters $p$ and $m$.
[{\hat{p}}_n=\frac{\overline{X}-S^2}{\overline{X}}][\hat{m}_n=\frac{\overline{X}^2}{\overline{X}-S^2}]
Proof
 The estimators of the parameters $m$ and $p$ by the Method of Moments are the solutions of the system of equations
$$mp =\bar{X},\quad  mp(1-p) = S^2.$$
Hence our equations for the method of moments are:
[\overline{X}=mp]
[S^2=mp (1-p).]

Simple arithmetic shows:
[S^2 = mp\left(1 - p\right) = \bar{X}\left(1 - p\right)]
[S^2=\bar{X}-\bar{X} p]
[\bar{X}p=\bar{X}-S^2, \mbox{ therefore } \hat{p}=\frac{\bar{X}-S^2}{\bar{X}}.]
Then,
[\bar{X} = mp, \mbox{ that is, }  m \left(\frac{\bar{X}-S^2}{\bar{X}}\right)]
[\bar{X}=m\left(\frac{\bar{X}-S^2}{\bar{X}}\right), \mbox{ or } \hat{m}=\frac{\bar{X}^2}{\bar{X}-S^2}. ]

Comment: It would be good if you could expand on this, for example, by writing the formula for the MoM estimator.   Otherwise the answer is not self-contained; others (who don't already know the answer) will have to search online for "method of moments" etc. until they find the *real* answer.

Comment: is there a way to render the math here correctly?