# Bayesian estimation of $N$ of a binomial distribution

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, hierarchical-bayesian, bugs

This question is a technical follow-up of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113780/estimating-n-and-p-for-binomial-distribution-repeated-counting-of-partly-hi).

I have trouble understanding and replicating the model presented in [Raftery (1988): *Inference for the binomial $N$ parameter: a hierarchical Bayes approach*](http://pluto.huji.ac.il/%7Egalelidan/52558/Material/Raftery.pdf) in WinBUGS/OpenBUGS/JAGS. It is not *only* about code though so it should be on-topic here.

### Background

Let $x=(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})$ be a set of success counts from a binomial distribution with unknown $N$ and $\theta$. Further, I assume that $N$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\mu$ (as discussed in the paper). Then, each $x_{i}$ has a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda = \mu \theta$. I want to specify the priors in terms of $\lambda$ and $\theta$.

Assuming that I don't have any good prior knowledge about $N$ or $\theta$, I want to assign non-informative priors to both $\lambda$ and $\theta$. Say, my priors are $\lambda\sim \mathrm{Gamma}(0.001, 0.001)$ and $\theta\sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0, 1)$.

The author uses an improper prior of $p(N,\theta)\propto N^{-1}$ but WinBUGS does not accept improper priors.

### Example

In the paper (page 226), the following success counts of observed waterbucks are provided: $53, 57, 66, 67, 72$. I want to estimate $N$, the size of the population.

Here is how I tried to work out the example in WinBUGS (**updated** after @Stéphane Laurent's comment):

```r
model {

# Likelihood
  for (i in 1:N) {
    x[i] ~ dbin(theta, n)
  }
    
# Priors
    
n ~ dpois(mu)
lambda ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
theta ~ dunif(0, 1)
mu <- lambda/theta

}

# Data

list(x = c(53, 57, 66, 67, 72), N = 5)

# Initial values

list(n = 100, lambda = 100, theta  = 0.5)
list(n = 1000, lambda = 1000, theta  = 0.8)
list(n = 5000, lambda = 10, theta  = 0.2)
```

The model does *sill* not converge nicely after 500'000 samples with 20'000 burn-in samples. Here is the output of a JAGS run:

```
Inference for Bugs model at "jags_model_binomial.txt", fit using jags,
 5 chains, each with 5e+05 iterations (first 20000 discarded), n.thin  
 = 5  n.sims = 480000 iterations saved
         mu.vect  sd.vect   2.5%     25%     50%     75%    97.5%  Rhat  n.eff
lambda    63.081    5.222 53.135  59.609  62.938  66.385   73.856 1.001 480000
mu       542.917 1040.975 91.322 147.231 231.805 462.539 3484.324 1.018    300
n        542.906 1040.762 95.000 147.000 231.000 462.000 3484.000 1.018    300
theta      0.292    0.185  0.018   0.136   0.272   0.428    0.668 1.018    300
deviance  34.907    1.554 33.633  33.859  34.354  35.376   39.213 1.001  43000
```

### Questions

Clearly, I am missing something, but I can't see what exactly. I think my formulation of the model is wrong somewhere. So my questions are:

- Why does my model and its implementation not work?
- How could the model given by Raftery (1988) be formulated and implemented correctly?

Comment: Following the paper you should add `mu=lambda/theta` and replace  `n ~ dpois(lambda)` with `n ~ dpois(mu)`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks for the suggestion. I've changed the code accordingly. Sadly, the model still doesn't converge.

Comment: What happens when you sample $N<72$?

Comment: @user777 How do you mean? Truncate the Poisson distribution at 72?

Comment: If $N<72$, the likelihood is zero, because your model assumes that there are at least 72 waterbuck. I'm wondering if that is causing problems for the sampler.

Comment: @user777 You're right. I think that doesn't pose a problem to WinBUGS, though. For example: If any of my starting values for $N$ are below $72$, an error is produced. Further, after sampling, no MCMC-Sample for $N$ is below $72$.

Comment: I'm remembering something highly strange in WinBUGS: using a Poisson distribution as a prior, then the posterior is no longer integer-valued. Do you get non-integer values in the posterior sampling of `n` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks for the hint. I just inspected the posterior samples of $N$ in WinBUGS, they are all integers.

Comment: Ok. I would try to play on the prior of $\lambda$.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is convergence. I think the problem is that the sampler is poorly performing because of the high degree of correlation at the multiple levels of the model: $\hat{R}$ is low, while $n_{eff}$ is low relative to the total number of iterations. I would suggest just computing the posterior directly, for example, over a grid $\theta, N$.

Comment: @COOLSerdash You mentioned in the queston that "The author uses an improper prior of $p(N,θ)∝N^{−1}$ but WinBUGS does not accept improper priors." How do you represent it in the code afterwards? I happened to ask [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818274/how-to-represent-jeffreys-prior-1-n-in-winbugs) about "N^-1".

Comment: @TX I'm only aware of `dflat()`, which (I think) represents the improper uniform prior. The alternative would be to use a normal distribution with an very large variance. This would be a flat prior for all practical purposes, I believe. Maybe [this document](https://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/bugsbook_chapter5.pdf) can be of further help (e.g. section 5.2.4, page 84).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Well, since you got your code to work, it looks like this answer is a bit too late. But I've already written the code, so...*

For what it's worth, this is the same* model fit with `rstan`. It is estimated in 11 seconds on my consumer laptop, achieving a higher effective sample size for our parameters of interest $(N, \theta)$ in fewer iterations.

```r
raftery.model   <- "
    data{
        int     I;
        int     y[I];
    }
    parameters{
        real<lower=max(y)>  N;
        simplex[2]      theta;
    }
    transformed parameters{
    }
    model{
        vector[I]   Pr_y;
        
        for(i in 1:I){
            Pr_y[i] <-  binomial_coefficient_log(N, y[i])
                        +multiply_log(y[i],         theta[1])
                        +multiply_log((N-y[i]),     theta[2]);
        }
        increment_log_prob(sum(Pr_y));
        increment_log_prob(-log(N));            
    }
"
raft.data           <- list(y=c(53,57,66,67,72), I=5)
system.time(fit.test    <- stan(model_code=raftery.model, 
   data=raft.data, iter=10))
system.time(fit     <- stan(fit=fit.test, 
   data=raft.data, iter=10000, chains=5))
```

Note that I cast `theta` as a 2-simplex. This is just for numerical stability. The quantity of interest is `theta[1]`; obviously `theta[2]` is superfluous information.

*As you can see, the posterior summary is virtually identical, and promoting $N$ to a real quantity does not appear to have a substantive impact on our inferences.

The 97.5% quantile for $N$ is 50% larger for my model, but I think that's because stan's sampler is better at exploring the full range of the posterior than a simple random walk, so it can more easily make it into the tails. I may be wrong, though.

```r
            mean se_mean       sd   2.5%    25%    50%    75%   97.5% n_eff Rhat
N        1078.75  256.72 15159.79  94.44 148.28 230.61 461.63 4575.49  3487    1
theta[1]    0.29    0.00     0.19   0.01   0.14   0.27   0.42    0.67  2519    1
theta[2]    0.71    0.00     0.19   0.33   0.58   0.73   0.86    0.99  2519    1
lp__      -19.88    0.02     1.11 -22.89 -20.31 -19.54 -19.09  -18.82  3339    1
```

Taking the values of $N, \theta$ generated from stan, I use these to draw posterior predictive values $\tilde{y}$. We should not be surprised that mean of the posterior predictions $\tilde{y}$ is very near the mean of the sample data!

```r
N.samples   <- round(extract(fit, "N")[[1]])
theta.samples   <- extract(fit, "theta")[[1]]
y_pred  <- rbinom(50000, size=N.samples, prob=theta.samples[,1])
                   
mean(y_pred)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  32.00   58.00   63.00   63.04   68.00  102.00
```

To check whether the `rstan` sampler is a problem or not, I computed the posterior over a grid. We can see that the posterior is banana-shaped; this kind of posterior can be problematic for euclidian metric HMC. But let's check the numerical results. (The severity of the banana shape is actually suppressed here since $N$ is on the log scale.) If you think about the banana shape for a minute, you'll realize that it must lie on the line $\bar{y}=\theta N$.

[image: posterior over a grid]

The code below may confirm that our results from stan make sense.

```r
theta   <- seq(0+1e-10,1-1e-10, len=1e2)
N       <- round(seq(72, 5e5, len=1e5)); N[2]-N[1]
grid    <- expand.grid(N,theta)
y   <- c(53,57,66,67,72)
raftery.prob    <- function(x, z=y){
    N       <- x[1]
    theta   <- x[2]
    exp(sum(dbinom(z, size=N, prob=theta, log=T)))/N
}

post    <- matrix(apply(grid, 1, raftery.prob), nrow=length(N), 
                  ncol=length(theta), byrow=FALSE)    
approx(y=N, x=cumsum(rowSums(post))/sum(rowSums(post)), xout=0.975)
$x
[1] 0.975

$y
[1] 3236.665
```

Hm. This is not quite what I would have expected. Grid evaluation for the 97.5% quantile is closer to the JAGS results than to the `rstan` results. At the same time, I don't believe that the grid results should be taken as gospel because grid evaluation is making several rather coarse simplifications: grid resolution isn't too fine on the one hand, while on the other, we are (falsely) asserting that total probability in the grid must be 1, since we must draw a boundary (and finite grid points) for the problem to be computable (I'm still waiting on infinite RAM). In truth, our model has positive probability over $(0,1)\times\left\{N|N\in\mathbb{Z}\land N\ge72)\right\}$. But perhaps something more subtle is at play here.

Comment: +1 and accepted. I'm impressed! I also tried to use Stan for a comparison but couldn't transfer the model. My model takes about 2 minutes to estimate.

Comment: The one hiccup with stan for this problem is that all parameters must be real, so that makes it a little inconvenient. But since you can penalize the log-likelihood by any arbitrary function, you just have to go through the trouble to program it... And dig out the composed functions to do so...

Comment: Yes! That was exactly my problem. `n` can't be declared as an integer and I didn't know a workaround for the problem.

Comment: Around 2 minutes on my Desktop.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but say I wanted to predict the next $y_{i}$ from your model. Do you know how this could be done in the "generated quantities" block of Stan?

Comment: Mysteriously, the `round()` function in stan produces real-valued (!) outputs. Instead of using the GQ block, you'll have to gather `theta[1]` and `N` from the posterior samples and generate random deviates in R.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to use `round` to no avail. I'll use R then. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @COOLSerdash You may be interested in [this][1] question, where I ask which of the grid results or `rstan` results are more correct. [1] http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114366/is-rstan-or-my-grid-approximation-incorrect-deciding-between-conflicting-quanti

Answer (score 4):

Thanks again to @StéphaneLaurent and @user777 for their valuable input in the comments. After some tweaking of the prior for $\lambda$ I can now replicate the results from the paper of Raftery (1988).

Here is my analysis script and results using JAGS and R:

```r
    # Load packages
    #===============================================================================================================
    
sapply(c("ggplot2"
         , "rjags"
         , "R2jags"
         , "hdrcde"
         , "runjags"
         , "mcmcplots"
         , "KernSmooth"), library, character.only = TRUE)

#===============================================================================================================
# Model file
#===============================================================================================================

cat("
    model {

    # Likelihood    
    for (i in 1:N) {
      x[i] ~ dbin(theta, n)
    }
    
    # Prior       
    n ~ dpois(mu)
    lambda ~ dgamma(0.005, 0.005)
#     lambda ~ dunif(0, 1000)
    mu <- lambda/theta
    theta ~ dunif(0, 1)    
}    
", file="jags_model_binomial.txt")


#===============================================================================================================
# Data
#===============================================================================================================

data.list <- list(x = c(53, 57, 66, 67, 72, NA), N = 6) # Waterbuck example from Raftery (1988)

#===============================================================================================================
# Inits
#===============================================================================================================

jags.inits <- function() { 
  list(
    n = sample(max(data.list$x, na.rm = TRUE):1000, size = 1) 
    , theta = runif(1, 0, 1)
    , lambda = runif(1, 1, 10)
#     , cauchy  = runif(1, 1, 1000)
    #     , mu = runif(1, 0, 5)
  )
}



#===============================================================================================================
    # Run the chains
    #===============================================================================================================
    
    # Parameters to store
    
params <- c("n"
            , "theta"
            , "lambda"
            , "mu"
            , paste("x[", which(is.na(data.list[["x"]])), "]", sep = "")
)

# MCMC settings

niter <- 500000 # number of iterations
nburn <- 20000  # number of iterations to discard (the burn-in-period)
nchains <- 5    # number of chains

# Run JAGS

out <- jags(
  data                 = data.list
  , parameters.to.save = params
  , model.file         = "jags_model_binomial.txt"
  , n.chains           = nchains
  , n.iter             = niter
  , n.burnin           = nburn
  , n.thin             = 50
  , inits              = jags.inits
  , progress.bar       = "text")
```

Computation took around 98 seconds on my desktop pc.

```r
    # Inspect results
    #===============================================================================================================
    
print(out
      , digits = 2
      , intervals = c(0.025, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9,  0.975))
```

The results are:

```r
Inference for Bugs model at "jags_model_binomial.txt", fit using jags,
 5 chains, each with 5e+05 iterations (first 20000 discarded), n.thin = 50
 n.sims = 48000 iterations saved
         mu.vect sd.vect  2.5%    10%    25%    50%    75%     90%   97.5% Rhat n.eff
lambda     62.90    5.18 53.09  56.47  59.45  62.74  66.19   69.49   73.49    1 48000
mu        521.28  968.41 92.31 113.02 148.00 232.87 467.10 1058.17 3014.82    1  1600
n         521.73  968.54 95.00 114.00 148.00 233.00 467.00 1060.10 3028.00    1  1600
theta       0.29    0.18  0.02   0.06   0.13   0.27   0.42    0.55    0.66    1  1600
x[6]       63.03    7.33 49.00  54.00  58.00  63.00  68.00   72.00   78.00    1 36000
deviance   34.88    1.53 33.63  33.70  33.85  34.34  35.34   36.81   39.07    1 48000
```

The posterior mean of $N$ is $522$ and the posterior median is $233$. I calculated the posterior mode of $N$ on the log-scale and back-transformed the estimate:

```r
jagsfit.mcmc <- as.mcmc(out)
jagsfit.mcmc <- combine.mcmc(jagsfit.mcmc)

hpd.80 <- hdr.den(log(as.vector(jagsfit.mcmc[, "n"])), prob = c(80), den = bkde(log(as.vector(jagsfit.mcmc[, "n"])), gridsize = 10000))

exp(hpd.80$mode)

[1] 149.8161
```

And the 80%-HPD of $N$ is:

```r
(hpd.ints <- HPDinterval(jagsfit.mcmc, prob = c(0.8)))

               lower      upper
deviance 33.61011007  35.677810
lambda   56.08842502  69.089507
mu       72.42307587 580.027182
n        78.00000000 578.000000
theta     0.01026193   0.465714
x[6]     53.00000000  71.000000
```

The posterior mode for $N$ is $150$ and the 80%-HPD is $(78; 578)$ which is very close to the limits given in the paper which are $(80; 598)$.