# Bayesian Updating for a Discrete Rating Value

Tags: bayesian, nonparametric-bayes

I have an item for which I slowly collect rating values on a website. It is a movie item on a website and at the beginning it has no rating but I assign it a Gaussian prior $N(\mu_0, \sigma_0^2)$. A person comes on the website and gives it 4 out of 5 (note that I have only discrete ratings 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 stars)

My question is how can I update my prior now and get a posterior distribution for the mean of stars.

My second question is that let's say I consider the median of the scores as the final score that I want to show to people for that movie how can I do my updating then? I imagine I have to form a discrete prior as well.

And my last question is that if I wanted to assign a weight to each rating and find the weighted mean and median how can I do that?

These might be easy questions but I am very confused about these. If you know a book or paper that might have discussed a similar problem I appreciate if you could refer me to that too.

Comment: Would R code that does a fully Bayesian analysis for this be useful for you? Likely it would be based on direct simulation and not use any packages or involve MCMC.

Comment: Yes it would be really useful

Comment: I have done a bit more a would like feedback on how to make things clearer. Did you want me to tweet you?

Comment: Sorry I was busy and have not been able to check the code yet. Will do it during the weekend. Thanks a lot for suggestions

Comment: as a general read for that type of problem I recommend _Bayesian Data Analysis_ by Gelman et al.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general strategy for getting an initial grasp of Bayesian methods was suggested here [The connection between Bayesian statistics and generative modeling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7455/the-connection-between-bayesian-statistics-and-generative-modeling/40524#40524) and here [Bayesian meta analysis of residual standard deviation using BUGS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40731/bayesian-meta-analysis-of-residual-standard-deviation-using-bugs/40754#40754)

The below is a sketch of that for this question - were I think it works quite well - at least for me;-)

```
# Set of values that may become known (the rating from 1:5)
Knowns<-1:5
# A probability generating model for one such known (all equal probability)
sample(1:5,size=1,prob=c(.2,.2,.2,.2,.2))
# The possible unknowns that need to be _used_ to generate one such possible known
# First an example
PossibleUnknown<-c(.2,.2,.2,.2,.2)
sample(1:5,size=1,prob=PossibleUnknown)
# Note the unknowns here are the probabilities of a rating of 1,2, ... 5 and the known is the first rating given

# Getting a probability distribution for the possible unknowns (a prior distribution)
# Not immediate because its has 5 elements in 4 dimensions (as the probabilities must sum to 1)
# Fortunately Bayesians have one we can start with
library(MCMCpack) # Just used to get the prior
(PossibleUnknown<-rdirichlet(1,rep(1,5) ))
sum(PossibleUnknown)

# OK now using the two stage conceptualiaztion of Bayes by Don Rubin 1984 it is direct and transparent

# Number of MC smaples to generate
reps<-1000000
# Sample from prior of Possible UnknownS
PossibleUnknowns<-rdirichlet(reps,rep(1,5))
# Sample rating from data generating model for each Possible Unknown above
PossibleKnowns<-apply(PossibleUnknowns,1,function(x) sample(Knowns,size=1,prob=x) )
PossibleJoints<-cbind(PossibleUnknowns,PossibleKnowns)
head(PossibleJoints)

# The sample from the Posterior if 1st rating is 5 
# (those Possible Unknowns that generated PossibleKnowns = 5)
ConditionalUnknowns<-PossibleUnknowns[PossibleKnowns==5,]

# Plot prior and posterior marginals (separate rating probabilities) to _see_ whats going on
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 2:5) hist(PossibleUnknowns[,i],main=paste("Rating of",i),xlab="PossibleUnknown\n(probabilities)")
for(i in 2:5) hist(ConditionalUnknowns[,i],main=paste("Rating of",i),xlab="PossibleUnknown\n(probabilities)")

# Calculate marginal or expected probability for each rating separately
# Prior probabilities
apply(PossibleUnknowns,2,mean)
# Posterior probabilities
apply(ConditionalUnknowns,2,mean)
# A good guess at the prior probablities??
rep(1,5)/sum(rep(1,5))
# A good guess at the posterior probablities??
(rep(1,5) + c(0,0,0,0,1))/sum((rep(1,5) + c(0,0,0,0,1)))

# So if the next rating is a 5
(rep(1,5) + c(0,0,0,0,2))/sum((rep(1,5) + c(0,0,0,0,2)))
# Easy to directly check as for the second rating its prior is the posterior from 1st rating
PossibleUnknowns<-ConditionalUnknowns
PossibleKnowns<-apply(PossibleUnknowns,1,function(x) sample(Knowns,size=1,prob=x) )
ConditionalUnknowns<-PossibleUnknowns[PossibleKnowns==5,]
# Posterior probabilities
apply(ConditionalUnknowns,2,mean)
# Not bad
(rep(1,5) + c(0,0,0,0,2))/sum((rep(1,5) + c(0,0,0,0,2)))
# OK now read wiki dirichlet for the math
# Now the above was not just a warm exercise as for instance if you want to 
# use different priors, perahps an empirical prior based on past ratings of 
# films of the same genre - you now know how to do that! 

# Now the mean rating if you are interested in that is the sum of probability of rating * rating
# Prior mean rating 
sum( rep(1,5)/sum(rep(1,5)) * Knowns )
# Posterior mean rating given first rating was a 5
 sum( (rep(1,5) + c(0,0,0,0,1))/sum((rep(1,5) + c(0,0,0,0,1))) * Knowns )
```

Comment: when you type an answer, there is a symbol "{}" above the text area, which allows you to insert some formatting for the code parts. I really recommend to use it for the code and remove the "boldness" from the non-code parts. In the current version it hurts my eyes ;)

Comment: @ steffen Sorry, I did try that and could not get it to work nor find help about it and now I have to get back to _real_ work

Comment: select everything you want to format as code, **THEN** click on "{}" and the formatting is done. There is no need to be offensive. I hoped that the smilie is enough to explain that I was joking.