# Prove $P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$?

Tags: conditional-probability, naive-bayes

I've been doing some learning for Native Bayes classification. I came across this formula, but I'm having trouble remembering it because I don't know how to get this formula. Can anyone explain how to get ${\displaystyle P(A|B)={\frac {P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}}}$?

Comment: $$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$ is the universally accepted _definition_ of what $P(A\mid B)$ means, and there is no way to "get this formula" unless you have some _alternative_  definition of the meaning of $P(A\mid B)$ from which we could arrive at $P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$.

Comment: My answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/239042/127790) has some pictures that might help.

Answer (score 5):

As already pointed out in the comment, the statement 
$$
{\displaystyle P(A|B):={\frac {P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}}}
$$
is the very definition of the *conditional probability*. Check for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) on wikipedia for an overview.

If you have trouble to remember the definition,

- maybe try to imagine how you would try to literally *condition on something (event)*.
- how would you write such an expression, if you would condition on the whole event space $\Omega$ - what would you expect as an outcome
- and for the peace of mind, show that ${\displaystyle P(\cdot|B):={\frac {P(\cdot\cap B)}{P(B)}}}$ is indeed a probability measure itself